# How to control ListView in another XML?

Tags: android

```
LayoutInflater factorys = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);//获取
MainActivity中LayoutInflater （上下文参数）
View view= factorys.inflate(R.layout.bluetooth_list, null);//获取View 对象
TextView test = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_test);

Toast.makeText(this, test.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
test.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0,0,100));
```

The TextView is in another XML, Toast is work, but setBackgroundColor is not 
Why? This is just a test. My final target is set ListView in another XML.

Comment: your ques is confusing. What are you actually trying to achieve? Do you want to change the text view background that belongs to other activity or you want to access list view from another activity?

Answer (score 0):

you are only using the text [**test.getText().toString()**] from the textView not the textview . so what ever the attributes you are applying to textview will not affect your Toast.

Answer (score -1):

you can use interface to get that or simpler you can create a static method for the class that inflates the text view

for example

```
public static void ChangeTextcolor(){
test.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0,0,100));}
```

and then call it

```
thatClass.ChangeTextcolor();
```

Comment: Static methods cannot access instance fields.